# When a remote notification is received, how to know whether the app is active at that time?

Tags: ios, notifications

When I receive a notification, I want to play a sound so I set the json message to `"sound":"mysound.mp3"` and it works fine when the app is inactive. When the app becomes active, I also want to play a sound when I receive a message, but I found it not easy.

if I add the play code to `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`, then if the app is inactive, the sound will be played twice: 1. receive a remote message; 2. user clicks the message and call the play sound code.

Is there any way to distinguish these two situations or any workaround?

Comment: Check for application life cycle method didBecomActive. If it calls then you should not play it again. If its not then play it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        // Play sound when the app is active
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! I forgot these enums.